# Eerie stop-motion short film about a character with amnesia in underground, concrete tunnels

Tags: story-identification, short-film, stop-motion-animation

This was a stop-motion short animation I think produced in the early 2000s.  It took place in a series of concrete corridors in the walls of a deep cylindrical shaft into the earth.  The inhabitants of this structure were looked down on by surface dwellers.  The protagonist I think was leading some kind of expedition into the tunnels when, through some mishap, he ends up decapitated.  One of the tunnel-dwellers saves him by reattaching his head to a new body(?), leaving him with amnesia, and he joins their community.

One characteristic and eerie scene I recall is the protagonist being chased through the tunnels by semi-humanoid monsters.  To escape them, he leads them down a hallway he had encountered before, that has a series of boreholes in one wall.  Out of the boreholes extend a network of red, fleshy veins that trail down the wall and across the floor.  These act as tripwires for the large carnivorous worms that live in the boreholes; when touched the worms immediately erupt and tear apart the other monsters.

In the end the protagonist I think regains his memories and is disgusted with the tunnel-dwellers.  By some mishap, he again is decapitated, and his head falls to the very bottom of the giant cylindrical shaft, where some large creature that lives there comes upon him and I think kills him.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's quite possible [Junkhead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ge18Ieyi9bI&t=1601s). Offical website is here: https://www.yamiken.com/junkhead (although this seems to be for an extended version of the original 30 minute short film).

Contains all the scenes listed in the question (linked is the scene with the worms) and due to grotesque violence is NSFW (unless your workplace is a lot weirder than mine).

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much!